# Is it webservice or web service?

Tags: web-services, terminology

Is it one word, or two?

I'm mostly asking because I want to know if in Java naming it should be "webService" or "webservice".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to English grammar rules rather than programming.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Such a difficult question can only be answered by a [Google Fight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=web+service&word2=webservice). It's no contest: "Web Service" (two words) is the clear winner.

Interestingly, "website" vs. "web site" was the fight of yesterdecade, and the former eventually won out, it seems. For a long time, "web site" was the correct form. Perhaps "webservice" will catch on in the same manner. For now, not so.

Comment: Adding quotes around "web service" in your GoogleFight changes the game. Webservice wins.

Comment: Visual Studio's spell checker still marks "webservice" as a typo (as does SO's, which I can see while typing this), so apparently is still fighting for it's liberation.

Answer (score 7):

W3C says two words. Check out [their glossary](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-gloss/) on the subject.

Answer (score 6):

According to Wikipedia: [two words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service).

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion it should be two words.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged the question `web-services`, I think you should add "web-service" to the list of possibility. Of course, that doesn't work for Java.

I would use two words for now in case someone unfamiliar with the term is reading your code.

Comment: Tags can't have spaces in them, so I think that's a two-words answer. Perhaps the tag would be "web services" if that were an option.

Comment: @Chess: dashes (`-`) in tags represent spaces, since tags themselves are space-delimited.

Comment: Good point. I guess "web services" is it then.

Answer (score 2):

When Google fight is made correctly, quotation marks around words separated by spaces, there is no clear winner. 
[Google Fight done correctly](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22web+service%22&word2=webservice)

I would believe what W3C says and use "web service".